# Do I understand the concept of $x^{0.84}$ correctly?

Tags: soft-question, collatz-conjecture, open-problem

I'm trying to understand the concept of $x^{0.84}$ that Jeffrey Lagarias found for Collatz Conjecture. If I'm wrong, please correct me with an answer. I understand such that,

Suppose the interval $\left[1, 2^{1\,000\,000} \right]$ is given. In this interval we have at least $\lfloor{(2^{1\,000\,000}})^{0.84}\rfloor=2^{840\,000}$ natural numbers which is goes to $1$. In other words, we can choose at least such $2^{840\,000}$ natural numbers from this sequence $\left\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\cdots 2^{1\,000\,000} \right\}$, which goes to $1$. Or, there are  at least $2^{840\,000}$ natural numbers  in this interval $\left[1, 2^{1\,000\,000} \right]$ (But, we don't know exactly what the numbers are ?), which gives result $1$. So, Collatz Conjecture is correct for at least $2^{840\,000}$ natural numbers.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: What do you mean with the "concept of $x^{0.84}$?

Comment: @Wojowu English is not my native language. I mean Lagarias has wrote it in your book.

Comment: what do you mean by goes to 1

Comment: @SakethMalyala Do you know about Collatz Conjecture?

Comment: @Wojowu I guess it's a reference to [Bounds for the 3x+1 Problem using Difference Inequalities](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0205002) by Krasikov and Lagarias, which proves that at least x^0.84 of the integers (er, naturals) less than x eventually go to 1.

Comment: As an aside... I would imagine that by $1.000.000$ here you mean $10^6$ and the periods are used just as a matter of grouping the digits to separate to more quickly identify the positions of the digits... but then you also use $0.84$ and this appears to be $84\cdot 10^{-2}$.  In America, we use commas to group the digits and periods for decimal points.  I am aware that other places do things differently, but I thought that if you used periods for grouping digits that you would use commas for decimal points instead of using periods for both...  How could you know how to interpret $1.234$?

Comment: I think your description is correct and I won't have an idea how to understand this differently.

Comment: My point is you should use more consistent notation.   If you want to use periods as decimal points, don't also use them for groupings or vice versa as if you use them for both it is ambiguous what you mean.

Comment: @JMoravitz I unserstood.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (OP:)... So, Collatz Conjecture is correct for at least $2^{840\,000}$ natural numbers. Is my understanding correct?

As I've read Lagarias & Krasikov your take is correct. However in your sentence which I've cited here you should have included the clause:

> ... So, Collatz Conjecture is correct for at least $2^{840\,000}$ natural numbers below $2^{1\,000\,000}$. (...)

Otherwise you come in conflict with the property, that even ***infinitely many*** numbers are known to converge to $1$, for instance from the infinite sequence $\{1,2,4,8,\cdots,2^k, \cdots\}$ or from the infinite sequence $\{1,5,21,85, \cdots , {4^k-1 \over 3} , \cdots \}$ or from ***infinitely many*** infinite sequences generated in this style.

Comment: Thank you answer and edit the question. Did you read Terence Tao`s partial proof? can I ask?

Comment: @Elementary - yes, you can ask. On a nice sunny sunday morning as it is today here:  I'm a really calm and happy human... I've read the T. Tao's proof but it is way over my head, I even did not grasp yet what he's talking about at all... :-(

Comment: @Elementary - the arxiv-text was impossible for me to grasp. But the conversation on T.Tao's blog https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2019/09/10/almost-all-collatz-orbits-attain-almost-bounded-values/ has a much enlightening factor.

Comment: I agree...It is important to be happy on all Sunday mornings.  A shaken/sad/heartbroken man can not do mathematics..

Comment: Yes, we can draw a conclusion from the discussions.

Comment: @Elementary - "yes" to all. I'm going out now for a while. Have a nice day...

Comment: Have a nice day...

Answer (score -3):

$x^{0.84} = x^\frac{21}{25} = (x^{21})^\frac{1}{25}$, which is the unique solution $y$ of $y^{25} = x^{21}$. For irrational $y$, $x^y = \sup_{z\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(-\infty,y)}x^z = \inf_{z\in\mathbb{Q}\cap(y,\infty)} x^z$.

Comment: Is this answer about the collatz conjecture?